# init.sql is added as directory in docker-compose with postgressql

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

Im still having issues with postgres init.sql file,the docker-compose.yml is as follows

```sh
  volumes:
          - ./dbscripts/init.sql :/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
          - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

init.sql is created as directory in dbscripts in local folder and docker-entrypoint-initdb.d in container..

I'm new to docker and postgres.Any help is hightly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the space after init.sql

```sh
  volumes:
          - ./dbscripts/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
          - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: Thanks very much ,actually realised that last night after spending 3 days on that issue :).